# How to create a notification bar on top of a windows form application?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-2.0

I am planning to create stackoverflow like top notification banner for my desktop, windows form application how can I create?I'm new to .Net world, help me proceed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put a SplitContainer in your form, Dock==Fill, Orientation==Horizontal.

Put your notification in the top panel and the rest in the bottom panel.
Use the Panel1Collapsed property to toggle your notification on and off.